# Debug node mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

How can I debug this error:

It's simple code, but I don't know why I'm getting the error.

```
module.exports.cliente = function(application, req, res){
    var cliente_id = req.query.id;
    console.log('cliente_id em cliente', req.query.id)
    var connection = application.config.dbConnection;
    var ClientesDAO = new 
    application.app.models.backOffice.ClientesDAO(connection);
    ClientesDAO.dadosCliente(cliente_id, function(err, dadosCliente){
        console.log('dadosCliente', dadosCliente)   
                        if (err) { 

                            console.log('entrou err getDadosCliente')
                            return (err); 
                        } 
                        console.log('entrou resolve getDadosCliente')

                        console.log('dadosClienteE', dadosCliente)                  
    })
}
```

My dadosCliente module:

```
ClientesDAO.prototype.dadosCliente = function(clienteid, callback){
 console.log('clienteid em dadosCliente', clienteid)
var client_id = new ObjectId.ObjectID(clienteid);
    this._connection.open(function(err, mongoClient){
        mongoClient.collection('clientes', function(err,collection){
            collection.find({_id:client_id}).toArray(function(err,result){
                        console.log('dadosCliente result', result)
                        callback(result);
                        mongoClient.close();
            })

        })
    })
}
```

And now my log:

```
cliente_id em cliente 5a4685503fdc5a2a616cd5e1
clienteid em dadosCliente 5a4685503fdc5a2a616cd5e1
dadosCliente result [ { _id: 5a4685503fdc5a2a616cd5e1,
    nome: 'Eva Oliveira',
    idade: '42',
    genero: 'feminino',
    email: 'eva.olveira@gmail.com' } ]
dadosCliente undefined
entrou err getDadosCliente
```

Comment: Please post english error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing in this call

> ClientesDAO.dadosCliente(cliente_id, function(err, dadosCliente){

a callback function which is waiting for 2 parameters.

After that, inside your dadosCliente module you are calling the callback function with only one parameter, which is supposed to be the error. So, you should call the callback method with the error previous to the result:

```
callback(err, result);
```

Comment: That was it..! Thanks